# Knockout - restrict input to only numbers with one decimal point

Tags: javascript, forms, knockout.js

I have the code below which does restrict the input to only numbers and a select number of key combinations. But I also want to restrict the input to only accept one decimal point.

```
number: {
            init: function (element) {
                // Allows only numbers with decimals
                $(element).on("keydown", function (event) {
                    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
                    if (event.keyCode === 46 || event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 9 || event.keyCode === 27 || event.keyCode === 13 ||
                        // Allow: Ctrl+A, Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V, Ctrl + X
                        ((event.keyCode === 65 || event.keyCode === 67 || event.keyCode === 86 || event.keyCode === 88) && (event.ctrlKey === true || event.metaKey === true)) ||
                        // Allow: .
                        (event.keyCode === 190 || event.keyCode === 110) ||
                        // Allow: home, end, left, right
                        (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                        // let it happen, don't do anything
                        return;
                    } else {
                        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                        if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

I tried to add `'$(element).val().indexOf('.') !== -1'` like below but it does not do anything and I can still type in as many periods I want. How should I actually restrict it?

```
if (event.shiftKey || ($(element).val().indexOf('.') !== -1 && (event.keyCode === 190 || event.keyCode === 110)) || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                event.preventDefault();
                        }
```

Comment: ...and then I come along and paste "lorem ipsum" into the input instead. :-)

Answer (score 1):

So I must say I don't really see the logic in allowing explicitly; instead you should exclude explicitly as by default everything is allowed. You buy a computer after it having passed all your criteria, you don't buy 10 computers, then throw away those that don't fit your criteria. So, no need to touch the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> & other function keys, you're making it needlessly complicated.
If you look carefully at your extremely long `if` clause, you will notice the following: 
`(event.keyCode === 190` under which you stated `// let it happen, don't do anything`. So periods will always be added regardless. Here are the gotchas with your current approach:

- with the `keydown` event, all keycodes produce the same *value* with <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> on or not, because they're the same *keys*. So you cannot distinguish between period `.` and semicolon `;`.
- with the `keydown` event, keycodes for the same number on a numpad and on the keyboard are *different*, because they are different *keys*.
- Disabling the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (like you did), forces AZERTY users to use Caps Lock because AZERTY keyboards produce the non-numerical char when Shift is off.

As a result you are much better off using the `keypress` event, which returns the *character value*. Here is a refactored and much more concise function, that achieves exactly the same:

```
 $('#jquery').on("keypress", function (event) {
   var k = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
   if (k === 46 && this.value.match(/\./g) || (k < 48 && k !== 46 ) || k > 57) {                            
     event.preventDefault();
   }
 });
```

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/5ay3cory/6/

NOTE: Because Mozilla Firefox sucks at making the difference between keydown and keypress, it messes up and disables all control keys too.

Comment: This does not serve my purpose. It only works properly if you enter the period as the first character but not when you enter after any other characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((yourString.match(new RegExp(".", "g")) || []).length > 1) {
  // yourString contains more than one "."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own code and thought I'd share it here:

```
// Allows only numbers with decimals
$(element).on("keydown", function(event) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
    if (event.keyCode === 46 || event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 9 || event.keyCode === 27 || event.keyCode === 13 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (event.keyCode === 65 && (event.ctrlKey === true || event.metaKey === true)) ||
        // Allow: .
        (event.keyCode === 190 || event.keyCode === 110) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
        // let it happen, but check for excessive periods
        if ((event.keyCode === 190 || event.keyCode === 110) && $(element).val().indexOf('.') !== -1) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        return;
    } else {
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

I added the following code where it allows certain keycodes:

```
if ((event.keyCode === 190 || event.keyCode === 110) && $(element).val().indexOf('.') !== -1) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: One could argue that this is better. However, I have fixed my code and it now works as well as this, and better because it doesn't impair AZERTY keyboard users by disabling Shift. (see http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/5ay3cory/6/, tested on Chrome, Opera, Mozilla FF, IE). Both your own answer and mine have a problem with Firefox though: your code doesn't allow period, and mine doesn't allow control keys (because Firefox sucks at implementing the keyboard standards).